# Random effects and cluster-robust standard errors

Tags: random-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors

I have read that when one adopts Random Effects (RE) there is no need to include cluster-robust standard errors because of the structure and functioning of the RE model itself.

Could anyone please elucidate on this - or indicate good references to better understand the rationale?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Of possible interest: [Modeling within group correlation - random effects, fixed effects, clustered standard errors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/373782/930). (Note that cluster robust SEs are not limited to RE models, but generally assume a moderate to large number of clusters. See also [Minimum cluster size requirements? Minimum sample size requirements for clustered standard errors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16488/930).)

Comment: When the random effects are at all close to their assumed distribution (e.g., Gaussian) and the overall model structure is reasonable, use the standard errors that come directly from the Bayesian or frequentist likeliihood-based approach.  And note that in some cases, sandwich variance estimators can be very inefficient (William Gould, president of Stata, wrote about this in the Stata Technical Bulletin many years ago).